# Pronomi combinati con 'ci'

Tags: pronouns, particles

Ciao a tutti, oggi mentre facevo lezione sui pronomi combinati mi sono imbattuta in un paio di casi "interessanti" che mi han messa in difficoltà.

In particolare, i pronomi combinati con "ci",
ad esempio

1. vi ci porto io dopo
2. ce li porto

La mia domanda è semplice: perché nel secondo esempio "ci" diventa "ce"?

Ciao e grazie! 
Fiona

Comment: Anche *ve li porto* (*porto quelle cose a voi*).

Comment: Nei pronomi combinati solo il pronome nella prima posizione "apre" la I in E.

Comment: Quando la particella pronominale "ci" precede un altro pronome o particella pronominale, si trasforma in "ce", ma non quando lo segue. Per esempio, "ce lo", "ce la", "ce li", "ce le", "ce ne". Ma invece si usa "mi ci", "ti ci", "vi ci".

Comment: Grazie delle vostre risposte, quindi secondo quello che dite è la posizione del CI (se è prima diventa CE, se dopo rimane CI) a fare la differenza... allora ho un'altra domanda: PERCHÉ SI DICE: "NON CI SI CREDE"? :/

Comment: @Charo You should expand that into an answer.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Adesso non ho tempo di farlo, lo farò appena posso.

Comment: @FionaD: Hai ragione: con il "si" impersonale, la combinazione è "ci si".

Comment: @FionaD: Nel caso di "non ci si crede" la combinazione "ci si" non è un pronome combinato. "Ci", in questo caso, significa "a questa cosa", come ad es. in "non ci si può pensare". Con il "si" impersonale non si hanno i pronomi combinati perché quel "si" è un soggetto.

Comment: @Benedetta: Il “ci” di “ci credo” è lo stesso di “ci porto i miei figli” (e che quindi diventa “ce li porto”), no?

Comment: @Benedetta: Potresti spiegare un po' meglio in che senso «quel "si" è un soggetto»?

Comment: @DaG: il "ci" non è lo stesso. In "ci credo" significa "a questa cosa", in "ci porto i miei figli" significa "in quel luogo".

Comment: @DaG: quando diciamo "In quel ristorante si mangia bene", il "si" è il soggetto impersonale del verbo. È come dire "In quel ristorante le persone mangiano bene". "Si" non indica un soggetto determinato (io, tu, lui...), ma è comunque il soggetto.

Comment: @Benedetta: Certo, grazie. Intendo che è lo stesso “ci” grammaticalmente, che costruisce vari complementi (di moto a luogo e altri), contrapposto al diverso “ci” che significa “a noi”.

Comment: @Benedetta: Quanto al “si”, ho difficoltà a capire la tua interpretazione: “si” è una particella passivante usata in verbi impersonali, che per loro stessa natura non possono avere un soggetto. Non ti confonderai con costruzioni come il francese *on mange*, in cui *on* è effettivamente un residuo di soggetto (<*homo*)? Secondo la tua interpretazione “si” sarebbe soggetto anche di “da qui si vedono gli alberi”?

Comment: @DaG: Anche il "ci" pronome indiretto per "a noi" sostituisce un complemento, in questo caso di termine. I tre "ci" hanno significati grammaticali differenti, non sono uno contrapposto all'altro.

Comment: @DaG: il "si" è passivante solo quando nella frase il complemento oggetto è espresso. Es. "In Italia con il pesce si beve il vino bianco", o come hai proposto "Da qui si vedono gli alberi". Quando la frase non prevede il complemento oggetto il "si" è impersonale, proprio come "on" del francese (che ha in più un uso leggermente più esteso).

Comment: @Benedetta: Grazie per le spiegazioni sul “ci”, ma continuano invece a lasciarmi perplesse quelle sul “si”. Quindi secondo te il “si” ha funzioni diverse in “oggi si mangia” e in “oggi si mangia pesce”?

Comment: @DaG: ho trovato questo articolo della Crusca, non so se può esserti utile. http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/usi-funzioni-pronome-clitico-si

Comment: @DenisNardin: Volevo scrivere quello che appare in un mio libro di grammatica, ma è molto simile a quello che ha scritto DaG nella sua risposta.

Comment: Grazie mille, @Benedetta, è un articolo davvero molto utile e chiarisce bene i diversi usi di “si”. (Ma, pur ritirandomi in buon ordine di fronte agli studiosi della Crusca che ne sanno ben più di me, in cuor mio non riesco a non trovare artificiosa la distinzione fra i due ruoli diversi di “si” in frasi come “oggi si mangia” (impersonale) e “oggi si mangia pesce” (passivante).)

Answer (score 4):

La regola è che «davanti a *lo*, *la*, *li*, *le* e *ne* la *i* di un altro pronome atono si trasforma in *e*: *mi lo*>*me lo*, *ci ne*>*ce ne*, ecc. Inoltre *le* e *gli* diventano *glie* invariabile, che normalmente si scrive unito al pronome successivo: “se vedo tua sorella *glielo* dico”» (Serianni, *Italiano*, VII.62).